# how to boolean a window through multiple objects that are grouped as one?

Tags: error

My log cabin logs are disappearing when I use the Boolean to try to create window holes. I know it must have something to do with the way I set up the logs, but am unsure how to fix it. I created one log and duplicated it up and down the building.

Anyone know how I can fix this issue or an alternative function to create holes through objects?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try switching the solver option.  Exact solver has given me unpredictable results in the past, it's best to only use it when it is the necessary option in my experience.

Comment: did you check your normals? if they are alright...pls provide blend file

Comment: Turns out switching out of exact was exactly what i needed.